# How to get another item then click on item in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to know how to get different item from selected item in gridview. I have gridview game of matching pictures. When i click on one image then that will flip and then when click on second image first will flip back. How to perform this animation? I want to get imageview of first selected image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by saving the last view in a variable

```
View lastView = null;
// .....
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {
        if(lastView != null) {
            // do something with the last view
        }

        // the rest of your code

        lastView = view;
    }

});
```

Not tested but should work.

Comment: What happens when you try it? any certain error appears in the logcat

Comment: there is no change in original item(Imageview). second imageview created and then changes happened on it.